# How to use curly braces in schema default value?

Tags: 6, database

I have a long varchar field that I'm using to save serialised data with `drupal_write_record`. I'd like to set the default value of the column to "a:0:{}" (which is `serialize(array())`).

However, when Drupal runs database updates, they are run through the `update_sql()` function which includes the default value in the query. This means that the '{' and '}' are interpreted as prefixing table names and removed, leaving the actual value of "a:0:" in the database, which is not what I want.

Is there a way to use curly braces in a field spec's "default" value?

Comment: May you show the code you use to update the database schema?

Answer (score 0):

In your schema, for the field you want to serialize, you can add the key `serialize => TRUE` and use the `drupal_write_record()` function to write the field in the database. After, you have just to send a simple `array()`(without `serialize()`) and Drupal will do it by himself.

You can have more information in the [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--schema.inc/group/schemaapi/7).

Comment: I am already doing this. You do have to serialise the value yourself when you define the field in your schema and database update function, e.g.: `$spec = array('default' => serialize(array()), 'type' => 'varchar', ...);` And yes, it works correctly for use from `drupal_write_record`... the real question is how to specify the default value that is compatible with that.

Comment: Ok I see, like you added on drupal.org it's a real bug, even in Drupal 7 and I didn't check but I guess it's the same in Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [db_query](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7), you can do something like this, normally only the curly braces inside the SQL string are replaced.

```
db_query("UPDATE {mytable} SET myfield = :data", array(':data' => "a:0:{}"));
```

Comment: What I was really after was a way to specify it in the schema using drupal schema api, so that the module could be deployed, etc.

Comment: We normally never provide a default for serialized fields, why do you need to do it?

Comment: Why do you ever have default data? Why do you ever have serialized fields? They are both valid, independently of each other. A default value can be set in the schema, and it works, so long as there is no curly braces in them.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, we use default values if we can and if it makes sense, but I never saw Drupal core and/or any other module use a default for serialized data. I agree it would be nice if you could specify a default, but AFAIK it isn't necessary.

Comment: Best thing todo is to open an issue (bug report or feature request) against Drupal 8 core, so it might get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a bug report for Drupal 6, [Impossible to insert serialized data with update_sql()](http://drupal.org/node/667714), but the bug was never fixed.

The issue is only for Drupal 6, as Drupal 7 doesn't use anymore `update_sql()`. The only workaround is using your own function, instead of `update_sql()`.

```
function mymodule_update_sql($sql) {
  $args = func_get_args();
  array_shift($args);

  $result = db_query($sql, $args);
  $sql = mymodule_query_get_string($sql, $args);
  return array('success' => $result !== FALSE, 'query' => check_plain($sql));
}

function mymodule_query_get_string($query) {
  $args = func_get_args();
  array_shift($args);
  $query = db_prefix_tables($query);

  if (isset($args[0]) and is_array($args[0])) {
    // All arguments are in one array.
    $args = $args[0];
  }
  _db_query_callback($args, TRUE);
  $query = preg_replace_callback(DB_QUERY_REGEXP, '_db_query_callback', $query);
  return $query;
}
```

You can use `mymodule_update_sql()` in the same way you use `db_query()`, as it can use placeholders.